# Sql event verses ScheduledExecutorService in Sevlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I build a web application for different form submission. My requirement is, i want to delete my database once in year on every 1st april automatically. For that i found two options.

`First is ScheduledExecutorService in servlet`. For example

```
@WebListener
public class BackgroundJobManager implements ServletContextListener {
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("BackgroundJobManager");
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new DailyJob(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Class DailyJob is

```
public class DailyJob implements Runnable  {
private static int lock=0;

    public void run() {
    int month=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day= Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE);
    if((day==1)&&(month==3)&&(lock==0))
    {
        //Some Logic To Delete Database
        lock=1;
    }
    if((day==2)&&(month==3)&&(lock==1))
    {
        lock=0;
    }
}
}
```

And `Second option is to use MySQL’s Event Scheduler at database`

```
CREATE EVENT `event_name` 
ON SCHEDULE schedule
[ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE] 
[ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
DO BEGIN
    -- event body
END;
```

The schedule can be assigned various settings, e.g.

- Run once on a specific date/time: AT ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM.SS’ e.g. AT
  ‘2011-06-01 02:00.00’
- Run once after a specific period has elapsed: AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP +
  INTERVAL n [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE] e.g. AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP +
  INTERVAL 1 DAY
- Run at specific intervals forever: EVERY n
  [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE] e.g. EVERY 1 DAY

My question is which approach is good and why?
Is there any another approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prefer **Event Scheduler at database**

- As database calls are considered as heavy calls, I will try to reduce the the calls.
- As the time/date is fixed (in your case, 1st april ) I dont need another extra service or logic layer

and hence I will try to implement in database itself